# Component depends on more than one scoped component?

Tags: java, android-studio, dependency-injection, dagger-2

I am using dagger 2 in my App. And now i am continuously facing this below error.

```
Error:(14, 1) error: @com.example.hp.daggerdemoexample.scope.UserScope com.example.hp.daggerdemoexample.component.ServerComponent depends on more than one scoped component:
@Singleton com.example.hp.daggerdemoexample.component.NetworkComponent
@Singleton com.example.hp.daggerdemoexample.component.DatabaseManagerComponent
```

Below is my Component Classes

ServerComponent.java

```
@UserScope
@Component(dependencies = {NetworkComponent.class, DatabaseManagerComponent.class}, modules = ServerModule.class)
public interface ServerComponent extends NetworkComponent, DatabaseManagerComponent {
      void inject(MainActivity mainActivity);
      void inject(RecyclerViewFragment mainActivity);
}
```

NetworkComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules={ApplicationModule.class, NetworkCallModule.class})
public interface NetworkComponent {
    Retrofit retrofit();
    OkHttpClient okHttpClient();
}
```

DatabaseManagerComponent.java

```
@Singleton
@Component (modules = DatabaseManagerModule.class)
public interface DatabaseManagerComponent {
    DBFlowHelper dbFLow();
}
```

UserScope.java

```
@Scope
public @interface UserScope {

}
```

And ApplicationData Class

ApplicationData.java

```
public class ApplicationData extends Application {

    private NetworkComponent mNetComponent;
    private ServerComponent mServerComponent;
    private DatabaseManagerComponent mDatabaseManagerComponent;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        FlowManager.init(this);

        mNetComponent = DaggerNetworkComponent.builder()
                .applicationModule(new ApplicationModule(this))
                .networkCallModule(new NetworkCallModule("https:XXXXXXXX"))
                .build();

        mDatabaseManagerComponent = DaggerDatabaseManagerComponent.builder()
                .databaseManagerModule(new DatabaseManagerModule())
                .build();

        mServerComponent = DaggerServerComponent.builder()//Error in this line due to ServerComponent Class DaggerServerComponent
                .networkComponent(mNetComponent)
                .databaseManagerComponent(mDatabaseManagerComponent)
                .serverModule(new ServerModule())
                .build();
    }

    public DatabaseManagerComponent getDatabaseManagerComponent(){
        return mDatabaseManagerComponent;
    }

    public NetworkComponent getNetworkComponent(){
        return mNetComponent;
    }

    public ServerComponent getServerComponent(){
        return mServerComponent;
    }
}
```

Help me any one how to fix this issue.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You depend on multiple scoped components here `@Component(dependencies = {NetworkComponent.class, DatabaseManagerComponent.class}`

Comment: I know boss how to remove this error?

Comment: Have a single `@Singleton` scoped component which contains `NetworkModule` and `DatabaseManagerModule`

Comment: Are you telling to use *one* component instead of those *three*?
It's awkard that I can't rely on others components event if they have the same scope annotation
I have the same issue and I want to have decopuled functionality objects not single component.